# Using delimiter to end loop with user input

Tags: c++

I want to create array without knowing size, depending only on user input.
The trick is the only input I'll get from user is raw data for array ex. 1 2 3 4 5.
My first idea was to create loop that collects data and count them until some delimiter is found. But I've got no idea how to do it, is it even possible?
Any ideas?

Comment: You can use `EOF`.

Comment: Sorry for not being specified. Input is from console, so I guess standard delimiter will be '\n'. Can I create variable for while/if statement that will check if char is int or new line character?

Comment: Input a string and use end of line or end of string.  Basic stuff you can google.

Comment: Arrays have a (compile-time) fixed size.  You'll probably want to use `std::vector` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is:

```
std::vector<int> data;
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), {},
          std::back_inserter(data));
```

Other:

```
std::vector<int> data;
int x;
while (std::cin >> x) {
    data.push_back(x);
}
```

Depending on requirements there are other approaches.

If data are provided in single line then:

```
std::vector<int> data;
std::string line;
if (std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::istringstream(line), {},
              std::back_inserter(data));
}
```

Comment: In 2nd version, everything other than int number will break loop, am I correct?
Is there a way to do that using dynamic arrays and pointers?